# Stray newline in file redirect

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, svn

I have a batch script with the following two lines in it.

```
svnversion . > myversion.txt
set /p MyVersion=<myversion.txt
```

This has always worked without any problems, svnversion produces one line with the revision number of the sandbox and the next line assigns this revision number to an environment variable.

Since some weeks now this behaviour is broken and I don't know what the cause is. I do know what the effect is.

On my system (and only on my system, not on that of my collegue) the capture file 'myversion.txt' does no longer one line with the revision number but two lines. The first line is blank and the next line contains the revision number.

If I have a look with an hex editor I can see '0d0a32...' as content.

If I run the command without capturing the output then no blank line is produced. e.g:

```
c:...>svnversion .
22837

c:...>_
```

If I run the same command on the system of my collegue the blank line does not appear in the captured result. We both have identical systems.

As a result I can no longer use the script to capture the svn revision number.

Questions:
 - Does anybody have an idea on what is causing the newline in the captured result? 
 - Is there another way of capturing the svn revision number in a batch file environment?

Kind regards.

Comment: You could try `svnversion . | findstr /N "^"` at the command line and in a batch file. Did `svnversion . > myversion.txt` also creates two lines when you call it from the command line? Did you check if you have only one version of svnversion and what version it is? Exists anywhere a `svnversion.bat` file?

Comment: You could check the versions on the different computers with `svnversion --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in (myversion.txt) do set "MyVersion=%%a"

echo Version = %MyVersion%
```

Comment: Elegant solution, thanks! I should have thought about this myself. Tested the version done by #Mago, that one also works and it cuts out the temp file.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used `svnversion` - but it's odd that the file is different on the two machines. Perhaps there is a difference in the updates that have been applied?

Perhaps

```
 for /f %%a in ('svnversion . ') do set "MyVersion=%%a"
```

would produce a workable system, but the root cause of the problem should really be investigated and resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information (Subversion related):

svnversion behaviour changes when redirecting output(!?)

```
c:\...>svnversion .
22923:22924M

c:\...>svnversion . >temp.txt
c:\...>type temp.txt
M
22923:22924
```

Note that the not redirected output puts the 'M' (modified sandbox indicator) at the end of the revision numbers and in the redirected output on the first line.

I don't know why (or how) this is done. But yesterday I was working with an unmodified sandbox and I got an empty line in the redirected output.
Today I have modified the sandbox but I was missing the 'M' in my reports. Now I know why!

And here is a script to put it all back together again. (crude but it works for me, suggestions to improve it are welcome.)

```
::
:: test.cmd - concatinate output from svnversion
::

if '%1'=='SVNREV' goto svnrev

set SVNREV=
for /f %%a in ('svnversion .') do call test.cmd SVNREV %%a
echo SVNREV=%SVNREV%
goto end

:svnrev
set SVNREV=%2%SVNREV%
goto end

:end
```

Note that the following is *not* working. (don't ask me why)

```
set SVNREV=
for /f %%a in ('svnversion .') do set SVNREV=%%a%SVNREV%
echo SVNREV=%SVNREV%
```

Comment: Hmm. The reason for that is the delayedexpansion characteristic. You need a line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (preferably immediately after the opening `@echo off`) to invoke delayedexpansion mode, then `...SVNREV=%%a!SVNREV!` to accumulate the data. At least the newline mystery is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for at least SVN 1.9.1.

Described and acknowledged by Stefan Küng at [Re: 1.9.1 bug in svnversion?](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvn/archive-2015-09/0017.shtml)

Comment: I found out this morning, installed 1.9.3 and it is fixed.